# Code First Integrate all models

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

my code first EF go to integrate all the models in the db even the viewmodels , i dont know how can i limit code first just for models?

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
    MigrationsDirectory = @"Migrations\PTN";
}
```

The exception:

> $ exception {"The 'PTNCONTEXT' context backup template has been
>   changed since the database was created Use Migrations Code First to
>   update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/ fwlink /? LinkId =
>   238269). "} System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: I don't quite understand. Only the the types `T` declared as `DbSet<T>` in your context will be included.

Comment: it's not declared in dbset it 's in model view !!

Comment: EF does not normally add ViewModels to it's internal model. Sounds like you do not have DbSets for them,  so make sure you are not referring to the ViewModels from your entity models as well. It would help to see what models it is referring to. Try adding a migration to see what the problem is.